# word2vec : find words similar in a case insensitive manner

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, word2vec, case-sensitive

I have access to word vectors on a text corpus of my interest. Now, the issue I am faced with is that these vectors are case sensitive, i.e for example "Him" is different from "him" is different from "HIM".

I would like to find words most similar to the word "Him" is a case insensitive manner. I use the `distance.c` program that comes bundled with the Google `word2vec` package. Here is where I am faced with an issue.

Should I pass as arguments "Him him HIM" to the `distance.c` executable. This would return the sent of words closed to the 3 words.

Or should I run the `distance.c` program separately with each of the 3 arguments ("Him" and "him" and "HIM"), and then put together these lists in a sensible way to arrive at the most similar words? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find similar words in a case-insensitive manner, you should convert all your word vectors to lowercase or uppercase, and then run the compiled version of `distance.c`.

This is fairly easy to do using standard shell tools.

For example, if your original data in a file called `input.txt`, the following will work on most Unix-like shells.

```
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' < input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Well, that would have been easy to do. The issue is that I have access to only the binary word vectors generated from an extremely large dataset.

Comment: @suzee, How exactly are your binary word vectors formatted? Are they just bits representing whether a particular word occurred or not?

Comment: Hi Merlin, I am sorry for the last comment. What I meant is that I have a binary file(.bin) of word vectors.

Comment: @suzee, How is the `bin` file formatted? That is, how are the bytes interpretted?

Comment: We have the bin file shared by google in the following page.
https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/#Pre-trained_word_and_phrase_vectors
We want to use this in a case insensitive manner.
Is it possible to transform this without having the original data?

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the binary format to text, then manipulate as you see fit.